# android constraintlayout, ellipse does not work as expected

Tags: android-constraintlayout, ellipsis

Trying to use constraintlayout, but having problem to show ellipse properly.

It has three columns, left icon; middle part (which has two lines); right icon;

left icon should left align parent, and right icon should right align parent,
the middle part should left align the left icon.

```
| [left icon] | [first line][B]       | [right icon] |
|             | [second line][other]  |              |
```

The middle part "First line ......" when text is too long it should show ellipsis,
and the "Second line ..." when text is too long it should show ellipsis as well

[image]

but when the text are too long the first line run over the right side icon, and the second line does show ellipsis but whole line runs over the right icon as well, although they have

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_logo"
```

to set to be placed in left of the right icon ("@+id/_logo")

Why the code does not do it supposed to do, or something not right?

[image]

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"

    tools:background="#00880088"
    >

    <View android:id="@+id/top_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_divider"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/social_content_padding" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="36dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_divider"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="52dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/social_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/social_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_blue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"

        tools:background="#ff0000"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_first_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_check_icon"
        tools:text="First line, more text, asdfsdfa eee 888 eee 888 " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_check_icon"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause"
        tools:background="#ff0000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_second_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="220dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_msg_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"
        tools:text="Second line, test long text more more more eee 888 ===" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/_second_line"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/_second_line"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_second_line"
        tools:text="  \u2039 30 Nov 2018 \u203A" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/social_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/social_logo_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/_check_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"

        tools:background="#33ff00ff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rotate" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="20dp"

        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first go through the different results of using **toStartOf** and **toLeftOf**

using  **toStartOf** will result in this output.

[image]

using **toLeftOf** will result in this output.

[image]

As you can see, Using **toLeftOf** push the date view out of the screen in case of big text.

While **toStartOf** will not change the position of date view no matter how big or small the text is.

Hope you got the point.

Here is the your required layout using **toStartOf**.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"

    tools:background="#00880088"
    >

    <View android:id="@+id/top_divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#888"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_divider"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/social_content_padding" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="36dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_divider"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="52dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/social_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/social_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"

        tools:background="#ff0000"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_first_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_check_icon"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="first" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_check_icon"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        tools:background="#ff0000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_second_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_msg_time"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/_first_line"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"
        tools:text="second" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_msg_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/_second_line"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/_second_line"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_second_line"
        tools:text="  \u2039 30 Nov 2018 \u203A" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/social_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/social_logo_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"

        tools:background="#33ff00ff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/_top_horizontal_guideline_2"

        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it helps with first line, but does not work for second line. When the text="second line" is short the `android:id="@+id/_msg_time"` part does not align to it right, instead it right aligned to the right side icon.

Comment: I posted a screenshot, same after tried your updated answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly should be changed from the edited answer?

Comment: tried yours updated one, still when the text is short the icon in the first line and the "30 Nov..." part in the second line do not left align to the left side sibling. They right align to the right side icon, as the screenshot I posted. Could you post the full xml layout with your update?

Comment: I have shared the whole xml layout. Copy and paste into an empty xml file and you should see the desired result.

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For the first line (`id/_first_line`), you mixed left/right and start/end constraints together. Both ends of the dimension should use the same pair for match_constrains (0dp) to work. Change `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/_guideline"` to `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/_guideline"`.

For the second line (`id/_second_line`), you need to add `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` so that this view's constraints are enforced when it grows too big.